# passing data from child to parent in react and undefind is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to pass an array from child component to my parent component .
What i did in parent component is :

```
handlerfordata=(data)=>{
        console.log('Inside handlerfordata data is');
        console.log(data);
    }
Inide return in render .Note Child is name of my child component

return(
          <View>

           <Child  handlerfordata={this.handlerfordata()}/>
           </View>
      );
```

Now inside my child component i have done something like this

```
 handleSave = () => {
           //finalvalue is an array that is computed and i can see it in my console and handlesave is triggeed at onclick in child component inside return 
           console.log('finalValue is ',finalValue);
            this.props.handlerfordata(finalValue);
       }
```

Another thing is that child component gets rendered on the screen but i just want to access data from child component and not rendering it .

Answer (score 1):

Pass the reference for `handlerfordata` and not `this.handlerfordata()`.

It shuld be

```
<Child  handlerfordata={this.handlerfordata}/>
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Yes . I did this but i don't see any data coming from child component to parent component inside handlerfordata

Comment: It should work.Please put breakpoint here `this.props.handlerfordata(finalValue);` and check it

Comment: @satyajeetjha put a debugger there

Comment: I am getting undefined is not a function (evaluating _this.props.handlerfordata(finalValue))

Answer (score 1):

By adding this code

```
<Child  handlerfordata={this.handlerfordata()}/>
```

You are not passing the reference, rather you are calling this function.

Change it to

```
<Child  handlerfordata={this.handlerfordata}/>
```

which will just pass a reference.

Then you can call that from child component using props.

Comment: Can you also show us how your imports look like, make sure you don't make any mistake there?

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind your handler :

```
<Child handlerfordata={this.handlerfordata.bind(this)} />
```

Comment: I am using an arrow function so there is no need to bind .

Answer (score 0):

ReactJS is known for one way data flow(Top down) meaning whatever data that is flowing or passing, should be in one direction, from parent to child.

In the case where you need to pass data the other way round, perhaps try to apply redux state management instead.

In the code that you are trying as stated, it's only passing a method down from parent to child.

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to call the method you need to  pass the reference in the child element as

```
<Child  handlerfordata={this.handlerfordata}/>
```

You cannot access the data from child without rendering the child component.I prefer you to use redux so that all the states are there in a single store.